# Error when attempting to create new WinCE project in VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, and I'm trying to create a new WinCE project.
But when I create the project, an error occurs:

[image: error template]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you translate that into English?

Comment: Impossible found the path or a part of it 'C:\..........vstemplate'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What SKU of Visual Studio are you using (Express, Standard, Pro, Ultimate)?  Device development is only available in Professional or better, IIRC (it changed with every version of Studio).  If you have the proper SKU, you also have to ensure device development support was installed (it can be unchecked during install).  If both of those are true, then check to see if the file indicated exists - if not I'd do a repair or reinstall of Studio.